# I am trying to open my bootstrap css but unfortuntaly getting error using laravel

Tags: css, linux, laravel, permissions

Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

[image]

**link here**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" href="{{ url('') }}/assets/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Comment: share `htaccess` file and better way to link :  `{{asset('css/bootstrap.css')}}`

Comment: you can also use     {!! HTML::style('assets/css/bootstrap.css') !!} and check that your public folder has permission write this command under public directory "chown -R username:group storage
"

Comment: thank u i solved this issue from this command chmod -R 777 public it's working now